# MySQL - Calculation IFNULL value being returned instead of 0.00

Tags: mysql, percentage, ifnull

I have added a percentage calculation (%_SOLD - SOLD as a percentage of FOUND - line 3 below) to my query which is working to an extent but returning the IFNULL value instead of 0.00 when SOLD is being returned as NULL.

```
IFNULL(ROUND((SUM(CASE WHEN ((rows.type = 3) OR (rows.name = 'Labour')) THEN rows.price END)),2),0.00) AS FOUND,
IFNULL(ROUND((SUM(CASE WHEN (((rows.type = 3) OR (rows.name = 'Labour')) AND rows.status = 'A') THEN rows.price END)),2),0.00) AS SOLD,
IFNULL(ROUND((((SUM(CASE WHEN (((rows.type = 3) OR (rows.name = 'Labour')) AND rows.status = 'A') THEN rows.price END))*100.0)/(SUM(CASE WHEN ((rows.type = 3) OR (rows.name = 'Tyre Labour')) THEN rows.price END))),2),'na') AS '%_SOLD'
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
"FOUND"     "SOLD"      "%_SOLD"
"269.86"    "0.00"      "na"
"0.00"      "0.00"      "na"
```

Line 2 is correctly returning the IFNULL value because both FOUND and SOLD are 0.00, but I need Line 1 to return the calculated result (0.00) instead of the IFNULL value.

I tried inserting the IFNULL 0.00, used in the first 2 lines of the query, into the percentage calculation but it didn't work.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: if you are using COALESCE instead of ISNULL you get the same result?

Comment: i haven't used coalesce before, do you think it would fix this?